# Correct use of Realloc

Tags: c, realloc

This is the way I've been taught to use `realloc()`:

```
int *a = malloc(10);
a = realloc(a, 100); // Why do we do "a = .... ?"
if(a == NULL) 
//Deal with problem.....
```

Isn't that redundant? Can't i just do something like this? :

```
if(realloc(a, 100) == NULL) //Deal with the problem
```

Same for other realloc examples i've found around, for example:

```
int *oldPtr = malloc(10);
int * newPtr = realloc(oldPtr, 100);
if(newPtr == NULL) //deal with problems
else oldPtr = newPtr;
```

Can't i just do this instead? :

```
int *oldPtr = malloc(10);
if(realloc(oldPtr, 100) == NULL)  //deal with problems
//else not necessary, oldPtr has already been reallocated and has now 100 elements
```

Comment: It’s not redundant. `realloc` might return a different pointer and invalidate the old one. Read [`man realloc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc).

Comment: @Ryan: OTOH, the way the OP has been taught is *also* bad, since it leaks the original allocation if `realloc()` fails.

Comment: Realloc returns a pointer.  You have to collect it somewhere.

Comment: Corner consideration: If the new size is 0, special considerations are needed as as the return value from `realloc(...., 0)` is not necessarily an out-of-memory.  `realloc(...., more_than_zero)` returns `NULL` on out-of-memory and also may/may not return a non-out-of-memory  `NULL` on `realloc(...., 0)`.

Comment: This is not redundant. There is no guarantee that realloc() will return the same address.

Answer (score 11):

`realloc` returns a pointer to the resized buffer; this pointer value may be different from the original pointer value, so you *need* to save that return value somewhere.

`realloc` may return `NULL` if the request cannot be satsified (in which case the original buffer is left in place).  For that reason, you want to save the return value to a *different* pointer variable than the original.  Otherwise, you risk overwriting your original pointer with `NULL` and losing your only reference to that buffer.

Example:

```
size_t buf_size = 0; // keep track of our buffer size

// ...

int *a = malloc(sizeof *a * some_size); // initial allocation
if (a)
    buf_size = some_size;

// ...

int *tmp = realloc(a, sizeof *a * new_size); // reallocation
if (tmp) {
    a = tmp;             // save new pointer value
    buf_size = new_size; // and new buffer size
}
else {
    // realloc failure, handle as appropriate
}
```

Comment: [Actually, if `new_size` is zero, return-value `NULL` does not consistently mean error.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc)

Answer (score 4):

the correct way to call `realloc` is to save the return value in a temporary variable and check it for NULL.  That way if realloc has failed, you haven't lost your original memory.  For example:

```
int *a, *b;
a = malloc(10); 
b = realloc(a, 100);
if (b == NULL) {
    // handle error and exit
}
a = b;
```

EDIT: Note that if the error handling doesn't exit, you should put the last line above, i.e. `a = b;` inside an else clause.

Comment: You most likely wouldn't continue on the standard flow of execution in the function if memory allocation failed.  The error handling should exit.  If somehow you can handle the error and continue, definitely should be in an else.

Answer (score 3):

realloc on failure keeps the original pointer and size. realloc on success may not (and often does not) return the exact same pointer as the input.

So the proper solution is your third example.

```
int *oldPtr = malloc(10);
int * newPtr = realloc(oldPtr, 100);
if(newPtr == NULL) //deal with problems
else oldPtr = newPtr;
```

Comment: I am looking for clarity. If realloc does not return the exact same pointer, don't we encounter memory leaks?
Doesn't the following code cause leaks:
int *oldPtr = malloc(10);
int *newPtr = malloc(100);
oldPtr = newPtr; //we no longer have reference to the first malloc, hence cannot free it.

Comment: I got my answer, realloc frees the old memory on success, https://stackoverflow.com/a/34615642/7802476.
Does that mean if you use the old pointer after realloc (without the else statement) you get undefined behavior?

Answer (score 2):

This code snippet is wrong.

```
int *a = malloc(10);
a = realloc(a, 100); // Why do we do "a = .... ?"
if(a == NULL) 
//Deal with problem.....
```

If the call of `realloc` returns `NULL` then the previous value of the pointer `a` is lost. So there can be a memory leak because it will be impossible to free the memory allocated by the call of `malloc`.

If just to write

```
if(realloc(a, 100) == NULL) //Deal with the problem
```

then in turn the returned pointer of the call of the `realloc` can be lost.

This code snippet

```
int *oldPtr = malloc(10);
int * newPtr = realloc(oldPtr, 100);
if(newPtr == NULL) //deal with problems
else oldPtr = newPtr;
```

is correct. However if to write

```
int *oldPtr = malloc(10);
if(realloc(oldPtr, 100) == NULL)  //deal with problems
//else not necessary, oldPtr has already been reallocated and has now 100 elements
```

then again the returned pointer of the call of `realloc` can be lost.

From the description of `realloc` in the C Standard (7.22.3.5 The realloc function)

> 4 The realloc function returns a pointer to the new object (which may
>   have (**or may not have - added by me**) the same value as a pointer to the
>   old object, or a null pointer if the new object could not be
>   allocated.