# Realloc the first element of an array of structs - invalid old size; problems with (*pointer + 0)

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, realloc

I have an array of `structs sth`

```
#define NUM_ELEM 8


typedef struct sth {
    int* tab;
    int lenght;
} sth;

...

int main(void) {
    sth* arr;
    function_allocating_memory_and_values(&arr);
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

There are also in code functions, which take pointer to pointer to the array of structs and inside them the elements of the array are modified.

```
void minor_function(*sth element) {
    //Changes something
}
```

Inside the function, I have to pass the pointer to the i-th element. Here I present two options I have tried with comments:

```
void major_function(sth** array) {
     int index = 0;  //the value changes later
     ...
     minor_function(array[index]); //the argument was passed to the function without errors, but nothing happened; during debugging, I have seen also segmentation fault;
     minor_function( (*array + index)); //It worked
}
```

As I believe, `(*array + index)` is the pointer to the index-th element.
`(*array)[index]` is the index-th element.

**1) What is `array[index]` in case of a double pointer? Why it did not work?**

The related problem with the reallocation:
There is the function to decrease the size of the structure inside the `major_function`:

```
void clear(sth* a) { //free would clear more properly in terms of nomenclature, but I want to reuse the pointer
    a->tab = realloc(a->tab, NUM_ELEM*sizeof(int));
    a->tab[0] = 0;
    a->length = 1;
}
```

It has not returned any problems - until I have passed the function the first element of an array, the index 0:

```
(*array + index) == (*array + 0) == (*array) //It isn't the code from the program, it is an illuatration
```

Then I got an error:

```
realloc(): invalid old size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I would have thought, that *array would indicate the first element of the array - however, it does not happen.

2. What is the problem with `(*pointer)`?

**3) How to reallocate the first element?**

I would really appreciate your answers and explanation.

**EDIT**

I have done some additional research and debugging.

Here is a code for allocation:

```
#define NUMBERS 45

void stworz_zmienne(sth** arr) {
    *arr = realloc(*arr, (NUMBERS+3)*(sizeof(sth)));
    for (int i = 0; i<=NUMBERS+3; i++) {
        sth cell;
        cell.tab = NULL;
        cell.tab = realloc(kom.komorka, sizeof(int));
        cell.length = 1;
        cell.tab[0] = 0;
        (*arr)[i] = cell;
    }
    (*arr)[NUMBERS+1].cell[0] = -1;
    (*arr)[NUMBERS+2].cell[0] = 1;

}
```

I have found that:

```
int main(void) {
   sth* array = NULL;
   function_allocating_memory_and_values(&array);
   clear(&array[1]); //without errors
   clear(&array[0]); //realloc: invalid old size
```

I suppose that the first elementi is not allocated properly for realloc, but I don't know what is the cause and how to fix it.

Comment: `array[index]`  is not the same as `(*array + index)`  I think you need to learn pointers.

Comment: post the actual code

Comment: _"(*array + index) is the pointer to the index-th element. (*array)[index]"_, use `*(*array + index)` here, then that would be a true statement.  Also, need to see how `function_allocating_memory_and_values(&arr);` is defined.  Please edit post to add a [mcve].

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789295/correct-use-of-realloc

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions; I will keep in mind your information about pointers. However, could you please explain me, why my question is downvoted? In my opinion, it shows my attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

About first question :

```
void major_function(sth** array) {
 int index = 0;  //the value changes later
 ...
 minor_function(array[index]); // fails because pointing to somewhere undefined or not allocated in your case. 
 // Only array[0] could eventually be use because it is ‘equivalent’ to *array
 // nut here it would a bad idea
```

array is a pointer to a (pointer or array), so *array can be seen as an array and used to access sth elements like (*array)[index] or eventually ‘*array + index’. In this latter case in c, the + operation on a pointer or an array will increment by the size of array elements or what the pointer points to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not know, that array[index] in this case mean something undefined